# Creating <class> definitions programmatically in EclipseLink

Tags: java, jpa, osgi, eclipselink

I am trying to use EclipseLink in OSGi environment.

What I want to do is, building a provider bundle that exposes EntityManager to other bundles.

The problem is, entity classes can not be determined and written to persistence.xml file at compile time. So I want to be able to define entity classes programmatically. I can scan for all Entity classes, but as far as I could see, there is no way to define it in EclipseLink, while it is possible in Hibernate. (Hibernate has some different issues in OSGi environment, so I can not use it either)

How can I define entity classes programmatically ?

Note: Using spring is not an option for me; and defining ClassDescriptors from scratch is not acceptible. I must say that it is really stupid that such an essential feature is not supported neither in JPA nor EclipseLink directly.

Answer (score 1):

did you try `<jar-file>` tag in persistence.xml?

you can pack all your persistence classes into jar, include it into your persistence unit bundle and persistence xml.

more details in JPA2 spec 8.2.1.6.3

Comment: If I could do that, I could also add class names to the persistence.xml file. Any bundle can have its persistence classes and they can not be merged into a single one.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this?

```
<exclude-unlisted-classes>false<exclude-unlisted-classes>
```

Comment: Yes, but no chance. Despite blogs and articles about using JPA in Java SE environment claim, this parameter does not work in SE environment.